# Properties background image not working [React]

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to set the background image of a div depending on the value of a component property, the background doesn't show, however it does show when I harcode the background-image property in the css file.

Here is the component code :

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./Banner.css";

export default class Banner extends Component {
  render() {
    const style = {
      backgroundImage: `url("${this.props.image}")`,
    };
    return (
      <div className="banner" style={style}>
        Chez vous, partout et ailleurs
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the Banner.css file:

```css
.banner {
  /* background-image: url("../assets/images/moutains.png"); */
  background-size: cover;
  height: 170px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 170px;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  color: #fff;
}
```

In the parent component:

```js
<Banner image="../assets/images/moutains.png" text="" />
```

**EDIT:** Complete code and assets here: https://github.com/musk-coding/kasa
codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/musk-coding/kasa

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, you are trying to access the image directly in your Component using the inline CSS. You must move your image to the public folder.

**CODESANDBOX LINK:** https://codesandbox.io/s/image-relative-path-issue-orbkw?file=/src/components/Home.js

[image]

Code Changes:

```
export default class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    const imageURL = "./assets/images/island-waves.png";
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="slogan" style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${imageURL})` }}>
          Chez vous, partout et ailleurs
        </div>
        <Gallery />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**NOTE:** From React Docs, you can see the ways to add images in Component. [create-reac-app-images-docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/). But since you want an inline CSS, in that case we have to move our `assets` folder into the public folder to make sure that the image is properly referenced with our component.